# How to control filtering in Apache Traffic Server using C#.NET application?

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, traffic, icap

I need to set rules for filtering via Apache Traffic Server using C#.NET + MySQL.
Is it possible to do?
Actually, I want to install an ICAP server with client app, for setting filtering rules.